# discord.py rewrite help command

Tags: discord, discord.py

Does anyone have any idea/sources where I can find a way to have a help command, for example:
I add a command called **command1** then once I restart the bot, it adds it to the help command, but if I set it to hidden it doesn't show

Comment: The bot will have a `help` command by default.  To create your own help command, you can look at this part of the documentation: [Help Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using "client"

```py
client.remove_command("help")

async def help(ctx):
   await ctx.send("type text here")
```

if you are using "bot"

```py
bot.remove_command("help")

async def help(ctx):
   await ctx.send("type text here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have had this problem before as well as all discord bots come with a help command build in it you need to remove the prebuilt one using this line of code `bot.remove_command("help")` and then making you own help command:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Here are all my commands\nhelp - shows this")
    # or make an embed (https://codepen.io/orels/full/egZyxq) auto embed maker
```

Everything put together:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Here are all my commands\nhelp - shows this")
    # or make an embed (https://codepen.io/orels/full/egZyxq) auto embed 

client.run("TOKEN GOS HERE!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this:

```
bot.remove_command('help')
```

This is needed because bots have built-in help command.